# Better to filter using DISTINCT in query or use java's set when parsing said query's results

Tags: java, postgresql, set, unique, distinct

Question as in title. I'm querying a table to get a pair of values, and I only want to save 1 pair of each value. Is it quicker to use: the

- DISTINCT clause in PostgreSQL and put that responsibility on the DB
- Use Java's Set when unwrapping the query's results into objects

Both results should result in the same thing, but is one inherently better than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The less data you have to marshal, transmit, and unmarshal, the faster your operation will be. This means that, in your case, getting unique data out of the database is preferable to getting non-unique data out and deriving the unique set later.

Generally it is best to do as much of your data processing as possible in the database. That's what it's there for, after all. There is an effort/complexity threshold where it can make more sense to process data in your client code, but finding unique values is one of the simplest operations.